# Nodejs EC2 Cannot find module './lib/nodefs-handler'

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I just did a clean install of nodejs (v6.9.4) on an EC2 instance, however when I try and run my nodejs app I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib/nodefs-handler'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/asistio/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:12:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/asistio/node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js:7:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

When I try and install the module with `npm install nodefs-handler` I get the error `'nodefs-handler' is not in the npm registry.`

I am guessing the the nodefs-handler is some module within nodejs that hasn't been installed for some reason, but I can find any solutions as to how to resolve this.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nodefs-handler is a module which came up with nodejs installation try to run this:

`rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm`, reboot the machine and reinstall node js

or

remove /usr/local/lib/node_modules

```
$ sudo n 6.
$ sudo npm install -g npm@3.10.0
$ sudo npm install -g npm@next
$ sudo n 7.
```

Cheers :)

Comment: I reinstalled nodejs to version v7.2.0 and still getting the same error :( I followed these steps to install node: http://iconof.com/blog/how-to-install-setup-node-js-on-amazon-aws-ec2-complete-guide/ any idea what is missing?

Comment: remove node_modules